# Typescript create nested type based on parent key

Tags: typescript, discriminated-union, conditional-types

Trying to create status, subStatus type from an object.

The subStatus type is inferred from the status.

```
const APP_STATE = {
  success: {
    defaultX: {}
  },
  failed: {
    apiError: {},
    timeout: {}
  }
}

type AppStateFn<T, U = keyof T> = {
  status: U;
  subStatus: keyof T[U]; // U not working
}

type AppState = AppStateFn<typeof APP_STATE>;
```

How to extract nested subStatus based on status from the object?
This is required type

```
type AppStateManuallyTyped = {
  status: 'success',
  subStatus: 'defaultX'
} | {
  status: 'failed',
  subStatus: 'apiError' | 'timeout'
}
```

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAggBQQfQMoBU7oKIwLwwDeAsAFAwwQCuwwAphBAFxFkUUAmdAZgIZUAbKAA0WhAL5sY4gDRS+ASwF0OYqRV4AHBdgBOukLrGz1MKAoC2dEFSjGpk0o7JQAnprrxNm1FF5Q6ADEwAB50GRgAVXwYAGs6VxBuGHQAPhiScko-KCpmKIBuKWoAI19-PJZ4xOT0AG1IgF0CmAB6VqiYMBBYAHdDWIUwAHMyZ1I3Dy8fHM8COG9ygOCQyetkxBQMLGxUotIydphQSFgA6AA1Xl0FXhLlFgWZ-08gA)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is what you want ([playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAggBQQfQMoBU7oKIwLwwDeAUDDBAK7DACmEEAXEaWTACY0BmAhhQDZQAGk0IBfFqIA0LHgEs%20NNiJZluAB1nYATlpBaRUlTCiyAtjRAUoBicXHEoATzU14ataijcoNAGJgAHnQYGgAPHzA2CBgQACMAKxpgKAA%20fGYyAG0AaxpHGFkwGFzHEE4YdABdZVZyLygKRmK8gG4jSljPb0amErKKnLzKtrJRNtFB0vKqtodnVzh3Lp90xY96v0CnF37EFAwsbBSWoA)):

```js
const APP_STATE = {
  success: {
    defaultX: {}
  },
  failed: {
    apiError: {},
    timeout: {}
  }
}

type AppStateFn<T extends object> = {
  [key in keyof T]: {
    status: key;
    subStatus: keyof T[key];
  };
}[keyof T];

type AppState = AppStateFn<typeof APP_STATE>;
```

Resulting type is:

```js
type AppState = {
    status: "success";
    subStatus: "defaultX";
} | {
    status: "failed";
    subStatus: "apiError" | "timeout";
}
```

As to what is going on, first part of the type generates a type for each top-level property of input via [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html), and that generated type consists of that top-level property (`status: key;`) and all second-level properties (`subStatus: keyof T[key];`). Afterwards, through means of [indexed access type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html) `[keyof T]` extracts all resulting types and unionize them into single `|`-expression.

Comment: thank you
autocomplete seems bit off, its includes all the substatus

https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAggBQQfQMoBU7oKIwLwwDeAUDDBAK7DACmEEAXEaWTACY0BmAhhQDZQAGk0IBfFqIA0LHgEs+NNiJZluAB1nYATlpBaRUlTCiyAtjRAUoBicXHEoATzU14ataijcoNAGJgAHnQYGgAPHzA2CBgQACMAKxpgKAA+fGYyAG0AaxpHGFkwGFzHEE4YdABdZVZyLygKRmK8gG4jSljPb0amErKKnLzKtrJRNtFB0vKqtuI5pxc3D3rXAjh3Lp9-AIWLcsQUDCxsFNnQSFh1NSZ15e9VojrupoBySmo6CBfJcgpO+p6MAARBwePwhECYKIgA

Comment: Indeed it is: if you Ctrl-Space after adding quotes (e.g. `"subStatus": "<cursor here>"`), it shows all 3 fields. But without quotes (e.g. `"subStatus": <cursor here>`) it shows only the correct ones (plus a bunch of globals). Adding `const` to the first field (`status: 'success' as const`) results in extra autocompletion options both with and without quotes. TBH I struggle to explain why it behaves like that... In any case, resulting type of `const app` seems to be correct, and invalid combination of properties is highlighted as an error.